# How should I keep game board information?

Tags: java

I am working on a Bomberman game. My question is about arrays. I keep all data about monsters, heroes and walls in a String array. The data looks like:

```
WWWWWWWWWWW
WHWEWEWMWEW
WEWEWMWEWEW
WWWWWWWWWWW
```

where W = wall, E = empty, M = monster, H = hero

Then I compare it and if it is a wall I use wall image etc. When something moves I update array.

I would like to know is it a good manner? Or should I do it completely differently?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a more OOP-approach: Use different classes for the different elements and provide methods that describe the behaviour:

```
public abstract class CellElement{
    //TODO coordinates, constructor and getters

    public abstract void drawCell(Graphics g);
    public abstract CellElement explode();
}

public class Wall extends CellElement{
    //TODO constructor

    public void drawCell(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(wallimage , getX() , getY() , null);
    }

    public CellElement explode(){
        return new Empty(getX() , getY());
    }
}

//TODO other elements
```

The field would then look like this:

```
public class Field{
    private CellElement[][] field;

    ...
}
```

Note that this is just a stub, please don't copy-paste that - it most likely won't meet your exact requirements. E.g. the field might use a different DataStructure than a matrix to store the single cell-values.

Comment: I think I understand your idea but I have one question. To fill CellElement [][] field I should use for loop? Whenever I need to put a wall I must to create new object and keep them in this array?

Comment: @user3636661 yes, that's the basic idea. Create a new `Wall`-Object, or whatever you call the class representing cells that are walls and insert it at the position, where you want to fill in a `Wall`. And same for all other objects.

Comment: Ok. One more question. How Java knows when and which method drawCell use? I never call paintComponent(Graphics g) in my own code but it works in magic way :P  Is it because this method is override?

Comment: @user3636661 yup. The "magic" is called polymorphism (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help.